# Converting HTML with Bootstrap Styles to Image (PNG)

Tags: javascript, java, html, css

Is there any Java library that gives support for converting an HTML file containing CSS styles and bootstrap.css style to an image, preferably JPEG.

I tried using phantomjs but it gives me full screenshot of my HTML page and doesn't do any pagination while generating images if html file is of larger size.

Also I tried wkhtmltopdf but it is command line tool and seems to have trouble understanding bootstrap CSS things very well..

Is there any Java library which could perform this task?